# How to When (switch) condition do with kotlin android: for example i have multiple checkbox?

Tags: android, kotlin

How to When (switch) condition do with kotlin android: for example i have multiple checkbox.

```
// checkbox click method
    fun onCheckboxClicked(view :View){
        // Is the view now checked?
        val checked = (view as CheckBox).isChecked
        // Check which checkbox was clicked
        when (checked){
            cb_a.isChecked -> message(cb_a.text.toString() + " Checked ")
            else -> message(cb_a.text.toString() + " UnChecked ")


            cb_b.isChecked -> message(cb_b.text.toString() + " Checked ")
            else -> message(cb_b.text.toString() + " UnChecked ")
        }
    }
```

Here i am getting error in first else -> "**else must be the last testament of expression**", i checked document for kotlin where not mentioned about using multiple statements.

Or any other solution for multiple checkbox please share .

for java in android doc https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox , same thing i want to do with kotlin

Comment: you can write separate methods for both the checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // multiple checkbox click method
    fun onCheckboxClicked(view: View) {
        var checked = view as CheckBox
        if (cb_a == checked) {
            message(cb_a.text.toString() + if (cb_a.isChecked) " Checked " else " UnChecked ")
        }
        if (cb_n == checked) {
            message(cb_n.text.toString() + if (cb_n.isChecked) " Checked " else " UnChecked ")
        }}

    fun message(str: String) {
        Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
       }
```

I found the solution.

define method in name in xml resource file onClick attribute "**onCheckboxClicked**". Call the method in activity...check which one is checkbox has clicked.

Here is complete example i posted https://tutorial.eyehunt.in/android/android-checkbox-example-kotlin/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it following way:

```
fun onCheckboxClicked(view: View, b: Boolean) {
    when (view.id) {
        R.id.cb_one-> {
            if (b){
                cb_one.text = "Checked"
            }else{
                cb_one.text = "UnChecked"
            }
        }
        else -> {
            if (b){
                cb_two.text = "Checked"
            }else{
                cb_two.text = "UnChecked"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if there is 4 checkbox ? check this google doc for java https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox

Comment: you can have multiple conditions inside when @RKKanojia

Answer (score 1):

You can use only one else statement. It is not mandatory to use `else` statemtn. If you don't need you can omit `else` statement. For your case you can write your logic this way

```
fun onCheckboxClicked(view :View){
    when {
        cb_a.isChecked -> message(cb_a.text.toString() + " Checked ")
        !cb_a.isChecked -> message(cb_a.text.toString() + " UnChecked ")


        cb_b.isChecked -> message(cb_b.text.toString() + " Checked ")
        !cb_b.isChecked -> message(cb_b.text.toString() + " UnChecked ")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using **multiple else** conditions in single when (switch) statement

else condition in when is like default in switch statement.
You can have only one else statement

Refer Kotlin's documentation for when [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression)

Consider using **different approach** for this, **like if else statement** as you want to check for each checkbox's **checked** and **not checked** condition.
When statement doesn't fulfill this use case.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you need is these messages then you don't need `when` but a simple `if`:

```
fun onCheckboxClicked(view :View){
    val checkBox = view as CheckBox 
    if (checkBox.isChecked) {
        message(checkBox.text.toString() + " Checked ")
    } else {
        message(checkBox.text.toString() + " UnChecked ")
    }
}
```

or

```
fun onCheckboxClicked(view :View){
    val checkBox = view as CheckBox 
    message(checkBox.text.toString() + if (checkBox.isChecked) " Checked " else " UnChecked ") 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the same thing to cb_a and cb_b, so there is no need to distinguish which one is clicked, just

```
val checkBox = (view as CheckBox)
val msg = checkBox.text.toString() + 
             (if (checkBox.isChecked) " Checked" else " UnChecked")
message(msg)
```

If you need to distinguish it, you can use:

```
when (view.id) {
    R.id.cb_a -> do something only for cb_a
    R.id.cb_b -> do something only for cb_a
}
```